# Gapi Error in while using youtube data api in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, youtube-data-api, next.js, google-api-js-client

I have build up a project using Next.js. Here I have wanted to implement a feature using the YouTube Data API. The feature is when the user clicks the **youtube connect** button, a pop-up window opens and authenticates the user. After the authentication, the YouTube Data API gives a response which contains the basic info the user's channel. Sometimes it has worked fine. But, sometimes it has shown the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import { Fragment, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {gapi} from "../common/api";
import { GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID } from "../../helpers/Constants";
import { AthleteContext } from "../../context/AthleteContextProvider";
import { Button, message } from "antd";
import AthleteProfileService from "../../services/AthleteProfileService";


  const YouTubeConnect = () => {

    const athleteContext = useContext(AthleteContext);
    function authenticate() {
        return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
            .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                  function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
      }
      function loadClient() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY);
        return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
            .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
            execute();
          },
                  function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
      }
      // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
      function execute() {
        return gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
          "part": "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
          "mine": true
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                    console.log("Response", JSON.parse(response.body));
                    athleteContext.invokeYoutubeInfo(response.body);
                    AthleteProfileService.connectSocialAccount({
                      attrName: "youtube",
                      attrValue: JSON.parse(response.body).items[0].id
                  }).then(res => {
                      message.success("Youtube profile link added!");
                      athleteContext.setProfileUpdateStatus(true);
                  }).catch(err => {
                      console.log(err);
                      athleteContext.setProfileUpdateStatus(false);
                  })
                  },
                  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
      }

      function executeFinal() {      
        authenticate().then(() => {
            loadClient();
          })
      }

      gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID});
          });
      return (
          <Fragment>
               {/* <button onClick={() => authenticate().then(() => loadClient())}>auth</button> */}
               <Button onClick={() => executeFinal()}>Connect</Button>
          </Fragment>
      )
  }
  export default YouTubeConnect;
```

I have tried some solutions. But, it still shows the error. Please tell me where is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey there! Please consider blacking out your exposed credentials (such as your app's _client ID_) as these credentials can be exploited for mischievous purposes. I suggest that you should regenerate your credentials in Google's API console and then delete the credentials that you've exposed. See the following guides for more info: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en and https://cloud.google.com/security/compromised-credentials

Comment: An amendment to my previous comment: However, AFAIK, you probably have to regenerate the credentials and delete the existing credentials as the existing image probably cannot be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about this important issue. I will regenerate it again.